# Azure Table: Atomic operation for more than 100 rows

Tags: azure-table-storage

I have a situation where I may need to update more than 100 rows in Azure Table atomically so that system remain consistent. Consistency is very crucial for our application.
Now using EGT I can only update 100 rows in a transaction.

One thing I thought was to take a lease on Azure Blob and then update entire 100+ rows. This will ensure that all of them happens atomically.

Is this right way to solve this problem. Are there any recommended way to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

> Is this right way to solve this problem.

According to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/storage-concurrency#managing-concurrency-in-the-table-service), you could find the minimum blob lease time is 15 seconds. That means you need consider your application scalability. So I don't suggest you use the blob lease.

Since the azure table storage EGT has 100 operations limit(if you want to insert 135 records, you need insert twice), it very hard to maintain the consistency.

I suggest you could consider using the Azure SQL. Azure SQL now support the [TRANSACTION](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/begin-transaction-transact-sql). In my opinion, this is the most easily way to achieve your application consistency.